# The plugin firebase_admob could not be built due to the issue above

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, admob

I was iplementing ads using Ad Mob. Everything went well (from coding to tesing on emulator) but at the tim of building, I ran into this error. Please help me fix this bug. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'firebase_admob'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;27.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: C:\Users\RaghavTheGreat1\AppData\Local\Android

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 44s


The plugin firebase_admob could not be built due to the issue above.
```

Comment: It seems you have not accepted android licenses run this `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't share images of text.  Copy the text into the question and format it so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: @JideGuru I have tried that command several times but nothing happened.